# PHP JAXB Equivalent

Tags: php, xml, jaxb

Is there a PHP equivalent to JAXB?  It's proved very useful for Java development, and as a new PHP'er I'd like to use the same concepts JAXB provides in a PHP world.

Comment: JAXB does two things - java code generation from XML Schema, and runtime binding of XML to java objects. Which one you you want?

Comment: Runtime binding of XML->Object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was also trying to find the same thing before, but couldn't. So I decided to write my own library for PHP 5.3 which mirrors JAXB's annotations to bind objects to XML.

Check it out here: https://github.com/lampjunkie/xml-hitch

Hopefully others will find this useful.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a simple and based on the annotations PAXB: https://github.com/ziollek/PAXB. Check whether this solution is sufficient.

Sample classes with XML binding annotations

```
/**
 * @XmlElement(name="root")
 */
class SampleEntity {

    /**
     * @XmlElement(name="attribute-value", type="AttributeValueEntity")
     */
    private $nestedEntity;

    private $text;

    /**
     * @XmlElementWrapper(name="number-list")
     */
    private $number = array();


    public function __construct($number = array(), $nestedEntity = null, $text = "")
    {
        $this->number = $number;
        $this->nestedEntity = $nestedEntity;
        $this->text = $text;
    }
}

class AttributeValueEntity {

    /**
     * @XmlAttribute
     */
    private $attribute;

    /**
     * @XmlElement
     */
    private $value;

    /**
     * @param string $attribute
     * @param string $value
     */
    public function __construct($attribute = "", $value = "")
    {
        $this->attribute = $attribute;
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attribute;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

Marshalling example:

```
 $sampleEntity = new SampleEntity(
    array(1,2,3),
    new AttributeValueEntity('sample attribure', 'sample value'),
    'Sample text'
);

echo PAXB\Setup::getMarshaller()->marshall($sampleEntity, true);
```

and the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <attribute-value attribute="sample attribure">
        <value>sample value</value>
    </attribute-value>
    <text>Sample text</text>
    <number-list>
        <number>1</number>
        <number>2</number>
        <number>3</number>
    </number-list>
</root>
```

Unmarshalling

```
$xmlInput = '...'; //as above
/** @var SampleEntity $sampleEntity */
$sampleEntity = PAXB\Setup::getUnmarshaller()->unmarshall($xmlInput, 'SampleEntity');
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar to JAXB but for PHP,

[**PiXB**](http://www.pibx.de/) seems similar to JAXB,
actually I didn't tried it but looking at the examples seems promising

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/moyarada/XSD-to-PHP

Answer (score 0):

There is a composer package for it: sabre/xml. 
You can install it with composer require sabre/xml. 
There is a homepage for tutorials and examples 
See http://sabre.io/xml/

It is easy to use and feature rich and actively maintained.