# Data structure to save nested XML based data

Tags: php, xml, data-structures, recursion

I obtain this type of response via `curl`:

```
<ArrayOfServerFile>
    <ServerFile>
        ...
        <FileType>Folder</FileType>
        <Identifier>x123</Identifier>
        <Name>Client Templates</Name>
        ...
    </ServerFile>
    <ServerFile>
        ...
        <FileType>XpressDox Template</FileType>
        <Identifier>y456</Identifier>
        <Name>contact-information.xdtpl</Name>
        ...
    </ServerFile>
    ...
</ArrayOfServerFile>
```

I want to save this info in a tree-like `data structure`.

I have tried something like this:

```
// Pseudo-code:
function run_procedure()
{
    get XML data via curl

    if FileType == 'Folder'

        save name and other useful data into $tree_like_data_structure
        run_procedure() // recursive call

    else if FileType == 'XpressDox Template'

        save name and other useful data into $tree_like_data_structure
}

var_dump($tree_like_data_structure);
```

The idea is to represent saved data like this:

```
[0][0] -> data
        [1][0] -> data
        [1][1] -> data
        [1][2] -> [2][0] -> data
                  [2][1] -> data
        [1][3] -> data
```

I am pretty sure that this is not so hard to accomplish but I have lost a lot of time without success. Any tip is very welcome. Thanks.-

**EDIT 1**

My main concern is how obtain [depth][element] indexes <s>and how level data (type, name, content, etc)</s>.

**EDIT 2**

Basically this is a recursive programming problem. **Maybe it can be done via `while` statements more easily than with a recursive function?**

Comment: It's not really clear how the sample XML represents a tree.

Comment: `<FileType>Folder</FileType>` indicates a folder that can be navigable using `curl`. So when I find a folder I must to navigate into it. So my problem is how to save all this data.

Comment: Does it help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531632/php-jaxb-equivalent

Comment: @shiplu-mokadd-im I don't think so. I have to make a curl call every time a folder is found. Every call gets a new XML file to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [SimpleXML with the DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php) to create your array.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML('
<ArrayOfServerFile>
    <ServerFile>
        <FileType>Folder</FileType>
        <Identifier>x123</Identifier>
        <Name>Client Templates</Name>
    </ServerFile>
</ArrayOfServerFile>');

if (!$dom) {
    echo 'Error while parsing the document';
    exit;
}
$s = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
echo $s->ServerFile[0]->FileType;
```

Comment: Your answer is totally out of scope... I am talking about `data structures` and `recursion`.

Comment: I disagree. My point is if you already know the structure of your XML then you can save it into a SimpleXML object without any recursion necessary. It is already a tree. `$s->ServerFile[0]->FileType === "Folder";`

Comment: Yes, I thought that too. But what you must understand is that there is **no one unique XML file**. These files are dynamically downloaded when an element represents a folder `pseudo-code says: get XML data via curl`. The idea is to save and download data at the same time, building a tree-structure. Any way this is already solved. I'll put my solution when have time. Thanks.-

Comment: I see. It wasn't clear that the files could vary (so dynamic recursion would be necessary). Glad you figured it out.