# Is there any JAXB similar thing in Laravel?

Tags: php, xml, jaxb, laravel

I need JAXB similar thing in laravel. I need to perform CRUD operations on XML data. I already used JAXB. But i need the same in Laravel. I am new to Laravel. Any help regarding this will help me a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not included out of the box, but you could use this one:

https://github.com/lampjunkie/xml-hitch

referenced here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6313476/385402

It claims to be an equivalent in terms of functionality to JAXB.