# PHP package for XML communication

Tags: php, xml, soap

i try to build a client which has to communicate to server using XML. 
i want to use plain PHP objects which matches to nodes of XML. 
Is there a composer package for extended XML handling which can map php objects to xml nodes?

UPDATE:

I searched for a Java solution and found JAXB. This is what i need.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: i have searched for a java solution and found this question which helped me a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531632/php-jaxb-equivalent/19206345#19206345

Answer (score -1):

I found a composer package for it: sabre/xml.
Value objects of the package is what i am looking for. See http://sabre.io/xml/valueobjects/

UPDATE : I used it today. It is easy to use and feature rich. I recommend it to  every php developer.